# Attempted import error: 'configureStore' is not exported from './app/store'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, rxjs

I have this in my `store.js`:

```
import { configureStore } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import userReducer from "../features/userSlice";

export default configureStore({
  reducer: {
    user: userReducer,
  },
});
```

What am I supposed to import in `index.js`?
It shows: `Attempted import error: 'configureStore' is not exported from './app/store'`

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import "./index.css";
import App from "./App";
import { configureStore } from "./app/store";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
  Provider configureStore={configureStore}>
  <App/>
  </Provider>
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### **You are doing default export for `configureStore`, so you will need to import default it in other files**

```
import { configureStore } from "./app/store";
```

**TO**

```
import configureStore from "./app/store";
```

**Or `store` as it is recommended not to conflict with `configureStore` from `redux-toolkit`**

```
import store from "./app/store";
```

Comment: Add ups : Don't import "configureStore" let it be default "store" . 
Tip : create-react-app app_name --template redux  (with this you don't have to import redux afterwards)

Answer (score 0):

You're using default export. Either default import like

`import configureStore from "./app/store"`

or remove the default keyword from your export.